# httpd process always 256

Tags: apache, testing, process, stress

I am using Amazon EC2 and apache 2.4, when I conduct stress tests, the httpd max processes is always 256

```
[ec2-user@xxxxxx]ps aux | grep httpd
259
```

httpd conf

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
 StartServers       10
 MinSpareServers    10
 MaxSpareServers   64
 ServerLimit      1600
 MaxClients       1600
 MaxRequestsPerChild 3000
 </IfModule>
```

MPM conf

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

httpd -V

```
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

maybe I am missing something?

Comment: CPU(s):   16, Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz;      MemTotal:  65149192 kB

Comment: Don't post text as images please. Edit your question to contain all information in an indexable format

Comment: share your 00-mpm.conf file from conf.modules.d folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using MPM configuration after `LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so` line. Means remove MPM configuration form httpd.conf file and add in 00-mpm.conf file.

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
 StartServers       10
 MinSpareServers    10
 MaxSpareServers   64
 ServerLimit      1600
 MaxClients       1600
 MaxRequestsPerChild 3000
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Server MPM:     prefork;
  threaded:     no;
    forked:     yes (variable process count)

Comment: still not work, I check that apache is running as prefork。 but after increased  ServerLimit and MaxClients, still 256.

Comment: yes, already paste 00-mpm.conf file content in the question.Thank you.

Comment: Bingoooooooooooooooooo! it works now. Thank you so much!