# Increasing Apache max connection numbers with ServerLimit

Tags: apache

I would like to change the default max connection numbers in Apache as the number of processes is now

```
# ps -ef | grep apache2 | wc -l
152
```

I have read that I have to change `ServerLimit`, but I don't see that in apache config files.

```
# grep -r ServerLimit .
#
```

Where should I apply that?

UPDATE:

Regarding the MPM module, I see this in `mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf`:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers                     5
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers          10
        MaxRequestWorkers         150
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Should I increase `MaxRequestWorkers` only? Or I have to define `ServerLimit`?

Comment: confirm your apache httpd version?

Comment: It is `Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPM configuration setting located in conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf file. You can configure ServerLimit after LoadModule entry. You can refer [httpd process always 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206229/httpd-process-always-256/62207470#62207470)

Comment: The ServerLimit directive represents the upper limit of MaxRequestWorkers. You need to specify ServerLimit value.

Comment: So, if I set `MaxRequestWorkers` to 400, Is it fine to set `ServerLimit` to 600?

Comment: In the link you mentioned `ServerLimit` is less than `MaxRequestWorkers`

Comment: Moreover, the output of `Server MPM:` from `apache2 -V` is empty.

Comment: For best practices, `ServerLimit and MaxRequestWorkers` should be the same.

Comment: I ran `apache2buddy.pl` before change and hot `Your ServerLimit setting is 256` which is the default and `Your MaxRequestWorkers setting is 150`. Then I only changed those parameters to 500 without including any .so file. Again, I run the script and see `[ -- ] Your ServerLimit setting is 500` and `[ -- ] Your MaxRequestWorkers setting is 500`.

Comment: As I checked the number of apache2 processes, it is now 202 instead of 152 (before) which I think it is working fine. Thanks for the help.